# Estimate quantile of value in a vector

Tags: r, quantiles

I have a set of real numbers. I need to estimate the quantile of a new number. Is there any clean way to do this in R? in general?

I hope this is not ultra-trivial ;-)

Much appreciated for your response.

PK

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As whuber pointed out, you can use `ecdf`, which takes a vector and returns a function for getting the percentile of a value.

```
> percentile <- ecdf(1:10)
> percentile(8)
[1] 0.8
```

Comment: For expediency, `ecdf(1:10)(8)` also works.

Answer (score 17):

To expand on what whuber and cwarden stated, sometimes you want to use a function in a "classical" R way (for example, to use inside a magrittr pipe). Then you could write it yourself using `ecdf()`:

```
ecdf_fun <- function(x,perc) ecdf(x)(perc)
ecdf_fun(1:10,8)
>[1] 0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here do a great job of explaining computation of sample quantiles from an empirical CDF.  Here I will show an alternative to using the sample quantiles, which is to use a kernel density estimator for the distribution and then compute the relevant quantile of a given probability value in the kernel density estimate of the distribution.

This can easily be done using the `KDE` function in the [`utilities` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=utilities).  This function produces a kernel density estimator, with corresponding probability functions that can be called directly.  First we generate the KDE and load its probability functins to the global environment.

```
#Generate mock data
set.seed(1)
DATA <- rnorm(30)

#Generate KDE
MY_KDE <- utilities::KDE(DATA, to.environment = TRUE)
plot(MY_KDE)
MY_KDE

  Kernel Density Estimator (KDE) 
 
  Computed from 30 data points in the input 'DATA'
  Estimated bandwidth = 0.389054  
  Input degrees-of-freedom = Inf 
 
  Probability functions for the KDE are the following: 
 
      Density function:                   dkde * 
      Distribution function:              pkde * 
      Quantile function:                  qkde * 
      Random generation function:         rkde * 
 
  * This function is presently loaded in the global environment
```

[image]

Once the KDE has been generated, you can call the quantile function using any input probabilities you want.  (This is the function `qkde` which is part of the produced KDE object; in the code above we have loaded the function to the global environment so it can be called directly.)  In the present case we are using a KDE with a normal kernel, so the quantiles at the end-points are negative and positive infinity.

```
#Compute the quantile for given set of input probabilities
PROBS <- 0:20/20
qkde(PROBS)

 [1]        -Inf -1.91000509 -1.28454267 -0.90720648 -0.66908812
 [6] -0.48063573 -0.31756724 -0.17102207 -0.03661007  0.08855345
[11]  0.20675802  0.32005203  0.43046992  0.54023777  0.65204011
[16]  0.76947215  0.89796032  1.04690298  1.23554909  1.51450168
[21]         Inf
```

Answer (score 0):

If using dplyr, `cume_dist()` returns the percentile of a value.

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/ranking.html.

A plus of `cume_dist()` is it can be naturally used in a pipe (`%>%`):

````
library(tidyverse)
df=1:10 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate( 
    x = rnorm(n=n(), mean=50, sd=10),
    x_percentile = cume_dist(x))

> df
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   value     x x_percentile
   <int> <dbl>        <dbl>
 1     1  43.7          0.3
 2     2  44.8          0.5
 3     3  41.8          0.2
 4     4  59.6          0.9
 5     5  54.3          0.8
 6     6  44.7          0.4
 7     7  37.4          0.1
 8     8  52.1          0.6
 9     9  61.2          1  
10    10  52.3          0.7
> 
```
````